# Change default 'Save as...' folder of Device File Explorer of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

**Is there anyway to change the default 'Save as...' folder of Device File Explorer Android Studio 3.0 and above ?** 
I want to pick a file from my virtual device into my PC, but an error happens, I guess it relates to the permission.

> Error saving file(s) to local file system: Cannot create directory
>   C:\Users\ABC\Documents\AndroidStudio\DeviceExplorer\samsung-samsung_sm_n900a-127.0.0.1_6555\data\data\moneymanager.app.com\files

[image]

Answer (score 10):

For Googlers: Since some version of Android Studio, Device File Explorer's default saving location can be changed in `Settings - Tools - Device File Explorer - Download location`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found the option to change directory as such but to actually pull the file from the Device File Explorer I recommend the following steps:

1. Change the folder permissions through adb shell.
2. Pull the file using "adb pull". See example:
   C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>
   adb pull /data/data/com.example.b.expensewatcher/databases/myexpenses.db

/data/data/com.example.b.expensewatcher/databases/myexpenses.db: 1 file pulled. 3.3 MB/s (24576 bytes in 0.007s)

For more details:
 https://www.dev2qa.com/android-device-monitor-cannot-open-data-folder-resolve-method/

Comment: Make sure USB Debugging is on
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options